# Perforce Windows Explorer plugin: No workspace has been set for this connection

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to use Perforce from Windows Explorer (Windows 7), but the Perforce context menu doesn't have any of the useful commands (checkout, submit, etc). Instead it has a disabled entry that says, "No workspace has been set for this connection."

The troubleshooting page I found says, "The problem is that P4EXP [Perforce's Windows Explorer plugin) ignores p4v’s configuration. You can configure P4EXP from the command line." It then explains how to do that by entering three "p4 set" commands.

But when I enter those commands, they have no effect whatever. And I'm not sure why they should; I got the information I needed to enter (client name, port, and username) by running the "p4 client -o" command. In other words, I entered setting into P4 that I got from P4. There must be something else I need to do, or it would have worked from the get-go. But what?

Comment: From a command-line window, run `p4 set` with no arguments, and post the results. Also, post your precise version information by running `p4 -V`. Also, is there any chance that you're running the command-line `p4 set` commands as an ordinary user, but running your Windows Explorer windows as administrator, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

It is great that you have the context menu set with perforce with [windows explorer plugin](https://www.perforce.com/plugins-integrations/windows-explorer-plugin). In order to make it work, one needs to set up the environment variables that point to correct workspace (in contrast to svn, perforce does not have .svn directory in each versioning folder). This can be achieved with the following command:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=my_perforce_workspace
```

given, e.g., that your path is in `D:\my_perforce_workspace`. If you do not have p4 on your system, install it from [helix-command-line-client-p4](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-command-line-client-p4).

Additional links:

http://maillist.perforce.com/pipermail/perforce-user/2009-September/025858.html
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r17.1/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/P4CLIENT.html

Answer (score 1):

If `p4 set` shows the right settings but the Explorer plugin shows something else, the difference could be P4CONFIG (which lets you have different settings per-directory).  `cd` to the same folder you're trying to use the Explorer plugin in, and run `p4 set` there -- any difference?

Your comment about `p4 client -o` is a little confusing -- note that if you have no workspace defined, `p4 client -o` will give you a template for a new workspace, but it will *not* create it (you'd have to pipe it to `p4 client -i`).  The command you should be running to verify your connection is `p4 info`.